# Cache Data to Local HDD with Caffeine?

Tags: java, caching, redis, bigdata, ram

I’m developing a distributed application that retrieves data from a global `redis` cache and caches the data locally using [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). From my understanding Caffeine was designed to cache data in memory (RAM) and not to HDD.

While I’m interested in storing some of the data in RAM, I want the option to cache larger datasets in HDD. Caching the data received from the global cache repository to the local HDD would still allow me to access the data much faster as compared to requesting the same data thousands of times from `redis` over a network. The idea is to refresh the local data only when the data changes or after a certain amount of time elapses (similar to how Caffeine caches data to memory).

Is it possible to have `Caffeine` cache data to local disk?

Comment: Yes, but since Caffeine is focuses only on on-heap caching, you'll need to look at frameworks for these integrations. There are two strategies: 1) Use a secondary tiered cache that Caffeine evicts to and loads from, e.g. Infinispan's [support](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#persistence). 2) Wrapping the cached value to lazily transfer the data to disk, which can be assisted by using the policy api to traverse entries in hottest or coldest order. I was shown a sneak preview of a pre-print research paper that does this by offloading to persistent memory.

Comment: @BenManes Interesting, I never heard of Infinispan. I'm curious how Infinispan compares to Caffeine in terms of speed/performance. An online comparison of the two [showed that Caffine is about 5x faster](https://programmer.group/caffeine-the-king-of-local-cache-performance.html). Also, I'm curious why you are suggesting using Infinispan as a "secondary tier" instead of replacing Caffeine with Infinispan  altogether - as they both seem to solve the exact same problem and integrating two different frameworks will increase cost of deployment + maintenance..

Comment: @BenManes _Wrapping the cached value to lazily transfer the data to disk, which can be assisted by using the policy api to traverse entries in hottest or coldest order_ this sounds very interesting. Could you perhaps expand on this concept? Would I need to implement this completely on my own or is there an existing solution that wraps cache to local hard drive? Perhaps this could be expanded into a full fledged response to the OP.. Thanks!

Comment: That comes from our [benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks). Since then they migrated off their own implementation and [now use](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#eviction-strategies_configuring-memory-usage) Caffeine. Another vendor, Oracle Coherence, asked me to help so I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/oracle/coherence/pull/60) for their June LTS (delayed as champion is on vacation). Their next version would then offer similar functionality.

Comment: @BenManes Oh, wow.. I just realized I'm talking to the author of Caffeine! Thanks so much for taking the time to respond to my question!

Comment: Regarding (2), unfortunately since their work is not open-sourced you would have to do it yourself. I can provide some more details over email. In general local disk caching is not popular due to having higher latencies than a network roundtrip. The trend is towards in-memory local with remote caches that offer memory + flash to reduce capacity costs.

Comment: @BenManes Didn't know [network access can be faster than disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/238417/are-networks-now-faster-than-disks). A round trip within same data center takes _500,000 ns_ compared to _10,000,000 ns_ for disk seek (20x difference).  I'm curious, are there any circumstances where you'd recommend using a local disk over remote in memory cache? If not, what would be the real world use case of writing to local disk via `Infinispan` or writing a cache wrapper on top of Caffeine? Thanks for chiming in..

Comment: @BenManes RE: _Since then they migrated off their own implementation and now use Caffeine_ So in the current implementation, `Infinispan` should be just as fast as `Caffeine` and offering more features like ability to cache to disk? Is this assessment be correct? Thanks.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs For local disk you have to find a justified reason on a case-by-case basis. An old trick for faster Jenkins builds was to clone from a git reference repository, so you only paid the cost of the incremental catchup when performing a shallow checkout for a clean build. This reduced the time considerably with a scheduled task to keep the reference up to date. Similarly a hot server restart could validate its cached contents rather than drop them. You can benefit but its not a general purpose strategy anymore.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs You might not even have an option in some environments, e.g. GCP's cloudrun is diskless ([case study 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20210702035412/https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/sre.google/en//static/pdf/case-studies-infrastructure-change-management.pdf)), so local storage is always network attached.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs That is probably true about Infinispan and I would hope that the intermediate code would be negligible. I have not performance tested it since or used it myself. Other than their docs the most I can say is that their team seems smart, friendly, and responsive.

Comment: @BradfordGriggs The cache wrapper approach was mostly attractive to avoid reimplementing it anew (concurrency, eviction, tests, etc). Thanks to composition and reuse they had less code to maintain and got it done faster. That is good engineering when the cost are acceptable (e.g. small performance/memory overheads), which it was. Same could be said about implementing that yourself or taking an existing project; if Infinispan or others are good enough then that is wonderful as we're all too busy anyways!